# What is the structure behind $ \partial \partial M = \varnothing $?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, exterior-derivative

In my lectures about manifolds, I learned about the statement $ \partial \partial M = \varnothing $ where $M$ notates a manifold and $\partial M$ its boundary.

My professor said, it is similar to the statement in differential geometry, that $ d^2 = 0 $ where $d$ is the exterior derivative.

What is the underlying cause for $ \partial \partial M $ being always empty?
What theory connects the statements $d^2 = 0$ and $\partial\partial M = \varnothing$?
Are there similar statements like the two given?

Please note, that I am not looking for a proof or explanation of why $\partial \partial M = \varnothing$ is true. I am asking about a theory explaining the underlying structure of the given statements.

I believe it could be something about comology theory but please enlighten me.

Edit:

The comment from @Aurelio is a very good reformulation of my questions:

> My understanding is that OP wants to know the general framework in which to say that $\partial^2=0$
> is the same phenomenon as $d^2=0$.

Comment: I think that the underlying structure you are looking for is called a (homologically graded) chain complex. There is a beautiful theory behind it, and I hope you will be studying simplicial homology soon in your course. In differential geometry, you deal with cohomologically graded chain complexes. The difference between homological and cohomological is whether the differential decreases or increases the degree of whichever object you are dealing with, for an appropriate notion of _degree_.

Comment: I don't think that explains why the boundary of a manifold is boundary-less in terms of the exterior derivative.

Comment: Your question puzzles me, and seems rather vague. You say you are not asking for a proof, nor for an explanation, and therefore I presume you *know* a proof, and an explanation. And the proof is pretty simple. Knowing those, what else are you asking for?

Comment: @Randall it certainly does not _explain_. Like the [de Rham complex](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363804/126773) does not _explain_ why $\operatorname{div}\circ\operatorname{curl}=0$.

Comment: My interpretation is that OP wants to use the fact that $d^2=0$ in order to deduce that $\partial \partial M$ is empty.

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants to know the general framework in which to say that $\partial^2=0$ is the _same phenomenon_ as $\mathrm{d}^2=0$.

Comment: I want only to know the underlying structures/theories of those two (or maybe more? That's why i asked the third question) statements. We proofed in the lectures, why $d^2 = 0$ or $\partial\partial M = \varnothing$, so I'm not asking for details to those specific statements.

Comment: @Aurelio exactly. Thank you for reformulating my question. English is not my main language :-)

Comment: @DaveLunal in such case you might want to read about chain complexes, leading possibly to some homological algebra. In the geometric context, there is a beautiful relation between homological and cohomological worlds called Poincaré duality.

Comment: The most concrete connection between these is given by Stokes' theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation between $\partial$ and $d$ can be described as a duality of chain complexes. Here's a very rough outline of what I mean by that.

One basic object in homology theory is the [chain complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chain_complex), which is a sequence of spaces and maps between them. Throughout I'll use real vector spaces and linear maps, and use $0$ to denote the trivial vector space and the zero map. (Elsewhere, other categories are frequently used.)
$$
V_0\xrightarrow{\delta_1}V_1\xrightarrow{\delta_2}\dots\xrightarrow{\delta_N}V_N
$$
Such a sequence is a chain complex if the composition of any two maps is the zero map, i.e. $\delta_{i+1}\circ\delta_i=0$. We can take duals and adjoints and obtain a dual sequence.
$$
V_0^*\xleftarrow{\delta_1^*}V_1^*\xleftarrow{\delta_2^*}\dots\xleftarrow{\delta_N^*}V_N^*
$$
It's not difficult to show that if a sequence is a chain complex, then so is its dual.

On a compact $n$-manifold $M$, differential forms form a complex known as the De Rham complex.
$$
0\xrightarrow{d}\Omega^1M\xrightarrow{d}\Omega^2M\xrightarrow{d}\dots\xrightarrow{d}\Omega^nM\xrightarrow{d}0
$$
Here $\Omega^kM$ denotes the space of $k$-forms.

We can similarly construct an complex of submanifolds of $M$ using the boundary operator $\partial$, but making it into a sequence of vector spaces is not so trivial. One standard way is via [(smooth) singular simplicial chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology), but there are many others. In such a construction, we obtain vector spaces $C_k$ consisting of $k$-dimensional submanifolds (or some suitable generalization thereof), and formal linear combinations of these submanifolds. The boundary operator $\partial$ can be extended linearly to a map $C_{k+1}\to C_k$, giving rise to an chain complex, which I'll call the singular chain complex.
$$
0\xleftarrow{\partial}C_1M\xleftarrow{\partial}C_2M\xleftarrow{\partial}\dots\xleftarrow{\partial}C_nM\xleftarrow{\partial}0
$$
The key point is that the De Rham complex and the singular chain complex are dual to each other. The pairing is given by integration: If $S\in C_kM$ is a submanifold, and $\omega\in\Omega^kM$, we can define
$$
\langle\omega,S\rangle:=\int_S\omega|_{S}
$$
and extend this pairing linearly to all of $\Omega^kM\times C_kM$. Using Stokes' theorem
$$
\int_{S}d\omega|_{S}=\int_{\partial S}\omega|_{\partial S}
$$
we see that $d$ is the adjoint of $\partial$ with respect to this pairing. While this is not an isomorphism ($\Omega^kM$ is only a subset of $(C_kM)^*$) the two complexes are "essentially the same" (in a sense made precise by the De Rahm theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that it is not random (but more educational intention by my professor), that my two given "example" statements are so closely connected.
Are there any other examples, where one can describe certain statements as a duality of chain complexes?

Comment: Homology (roughly, the study of chain complexes and their applications) is a vast field, and shows up all over the place, especially in topology. Most courses/textbooks on algebraic topology will discuss the subject at length, giving all kinds of examples of exact sequences and maps between them.

Comment: Your definition of exactness is wrong. The equality $\delta_{i+1} \circ \delta_i = 0$ does not imply $\mathrm{ker}(\delta_{i+1}) = \mathrm{im}(\delta_i)$. It implies only $\mathrm{im}(\delta_i) \subset \mathrm{ker}(\delta_{i+1})$. You confused exact sequence and chain complex.

Comment: @Halbaroth Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out; I probably should have noticed that one.